# Multiprocessing with output saved in CSV

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here's is what I am trying to accomplish: I load a list of stocks tickers from a csv file and I use each tickers to load another csv file called `stock_prices` and compute stock returns at multiple time intervals (like 1 minute, 2 minutes, and so on). I want each processor to compute stock returns for a given stock and for a given time interval (like 1 minute stock returns) and then keep this time-series of returns on side and wait for all the processors to complete their jobs of processing the stock returns for all tickers and then combine all the stock returns into a database and then save the output in a csv file. I then want to repeat the process for a different time interval. I don't know how to write my code to save my output in a csv file. I will process my code in a cluster computer - with about 50 processors. Here's my code attempt:

```
import multiprocessing
import csv
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

#HERE I LOAD THE TICKER LIST. IT LOOKS LIKE ['AAPL', 'GOOG']
ticker = open('F:\ticker_list.csv',r)

 # THE INTERVAL FOR WHICH I WANT TO COMPUTE THE STOCK RETURNS
interval=['1','2','5']

def worker(TIC,INTER):
         #HERE I LOAD THE STOCK PRICES FOR A GIVEN TICKER
        df = pd.read_csv('C:\stock_prices_'+TIC+".csv", header=0)
...

# AFTER SOME COMPUTATION, df IS A TIME-SERIES OF STOCK RETURNS FOR A GIVEN STOCK AND FOR A TIME-INTERVAL

for inter in interval:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        jobs = []
        for i in range(50): #50 FOR THE NUMBER OF PROCESSORS
            # HERE I AM NOT SURE - DO I LOOP THROUGH MY LIST OF TICKERS
            # AND SUBMIT ONE TICKER FOR EACH WORKER AND THE CHOSEN 
            # TIME-INTERVAL?  
            p = Worker(ticker[i],INTER)
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()
        for j in jobs:
            j.join()

     # HERE I SAVE THE OUTPUT OF TIME-SERIES FOR ALL STOCKS FOR A
     # GIVEN TIME INTERVAL ... is it jobs? Here I wrote the code as
     # if jobs was in dataframe since df in worker is in dataframe format.
    jobs.to_csv("C:inter+"_stockreturns.csv", float_format='%.6f')
```

Comment: Multiprocessing only runs multiple processes on _one computer_. To run your problem on a cluster you'd need [cluster computing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing).

Comment: @RolandSmith thanks for letting me know. I assumed it was the same... it looks like that I need `PP`